# How to enforce override method's return type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
abstract class Car {
  abstract getYear() : number;  // <---- NOT ENFORCED!
}

class Honda extends Car {
  getYear() {
    return '1994' // <---- No errors.
  }
}
```

Comment: I see an error https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwsKCDeAUAgqJDPAgOYCmEAmtTgBQCUCAXAgHYCuAtiGpQA3MQD0YhAB4AtHJkIAcgHkAKggCiigGLKASpg0ARAIQEAvgQIo0GABIB7LgBNgCagA8I1Fxmy5CYhp6RihWfCJiBChaHiguBAByAEYATlSAFkSECWl5BUUHdygoBygwADpIy3MgA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it does indicate a problem:

> Property 'getYear' in type 'Honda' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Car'.
>     Type '() => string' is not assignable to type '() => number'.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

[example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwsKCDeAUAgqJDPAgOYCmEAmtTgBQCUCAXAgHYCuAtiGpQA3MQD0YhAB4AtHJkIAcgHkAKggCiigGLKASpg0ARAIQEAvgQIo0GABIB7LgBNgCagA8I1Fxmy5CYhp6RihWfCJiBChaHiguBAByAEYATlSAFkSECWl5BUUHdygoBygwADpIy3MgA)

[image: playground screenshot]